# Python-docx, vertical alignment in cell

Tags: ms-word, python-docx

Is it possible to vertically align text so it is vertically centered in a table cell?

Comment: This was already answered here.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946291/python-docx-center-table-content)

Moderators can delete my question if they think so.

Answer (score 4):

```
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL

table = document.add_table(3, 3)
table.cell(0, 0).vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.BOTTOM
```

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdCellVerticalAlignment.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 Tablename.Rows(0).Cells(0).VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
```